# Why the 0-1 binary Mask was not saved as binary

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I generated the 0-1 binary mask with PIL, then saved it. However, the mask was not binary, which consisted of [0,1,2], when I reopen the saved file. What is the problem and why did such a case happen?

The code to save the generated mask is

```
from PIL import Image
import glob    

files = glob.glob('file directorry/*')

for file in files:
    mask = Image.open(file).convert("L")
    mask = mask.point(lambda x: 0 if x<128 else 1)
    file_name = file.split('\\')[3]
    mask.save(file_name)
    
#count value, [0, 1]
print(np.unique(mask.getdata(),return_counts=True))
```

The code returns the message such as

```
(array([0, 1]), array([1229015,   18601], dtype=int64))
```

After that, I repone the saved mask file,

```
saved_mask = Image.open(saved_filepath)
print(np.unique(saved_mask.getdata(),return_counts=True))
```

and the message returns

```
(array([0, 1, 2]), array([1243816,    3576,     224], dtype=int64))
```

I thought the file was saved as binary, but why not?

Comment: What file format is the mask file?  A lossy format such as JPEG does not guarantee that exact pixel values will be preserved.

Comment: The file format was 'jpg'. The problem was solved by changing the format from 'jpg' to 'png'!